# CSV file start with description(say 12 lines) and actual data starts after that. How to use pandas function to achieve this scenario?

Tags: python

Suppose you have a csv file first 12 lines are description of the data actual data starts from line 13 (file has no headers) - say file A

part 1 of the question : How to access data from 13th line.

Part 2 of the question: Suppose client has given you the headers for your data( in the form of one liner csv file - say File B) now copy data from file A and the header information of File B :

1. into an excel file
2. into a database (oracle)

Comment: showing what you have tried so far is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

Pandas read_csv() has a parameter of skiprows which can be used in this case. Set skiprows to 12. As an example,

```
df = pd.read_csv('123.csv', skiprows=12)
```

Check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)